# Finding unused (compile-scoped) jars in multiple projects using maven ?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant, jar

I have a webapp that consists of multiple projects. We assemble using Ant and we suspect that some of the jars in /java directory are unneeded.

To find unneeded jars I ran

```
mvn dependency:analyze -DignoreNonCompile
```

to get a list of unused declared jars for each project. However it is possible that a jar unused by one project is still used by another. To check this, I ran

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to get the dependency structure of all projects.

Using information from these commands, I will now use a script to check if a jar exists such that it is unused in all projects that declare it. Is this a reasonable approach for compile-scoped jars? What about jars in other scopes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> However it is possible that a jar unused by one project is still used
>   by another.

I recommend to declare all needed dependencies as direct dependencies and not rely on transitive dependencies which might get removed in a newer version.

Define the versions of the dependencies in the DependencyManagement section of the common parent POM and omit the versions later when declaring the dependcies. Like this you can make sure you're using the same version of the dependencies in all your projects.

Comment: Yeah, that is a good idea. However, I would first need to figure out exactly which jars I need and which ones I do not need.